# Большая нагрузка на CPU при попытках подключиться к серверу

Tags: c#, cpu, нагрузка

При неудачный попытке подключиться, если по тем или иным причинам сокет недоступен или нет сети, то нагрузка на процессор возвышается до 25-30 процентов. Каким образом можно улучшить код в плане оптимизации?

```
private static void TryToConnect()  {
    IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(ip, 6633);
    while (true)  {
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
       if (isConnected == true)
           continue;
       try {
           client.Connect(ep);
           Console.WriteLine("Подключение было завершено успешно!");
           isConnected = true;
       } catch { Console.WriteLine("Сервер недоступен"); isConnected = false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: если isConnected==true после первого подключения. то ваш код никогда не будет пытаться проверить подключение.

Comment: Может вместо `continue;` поставить `break;` ?